# How to change key of lookup kwargs field in RetrieveAPIView in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Django REST Framework uses `pk` has the lookup field when using the 
`RetrieveApiView` and same has to be defined in the url `kwargs` .

This makes the url look like :

```
url(r'^(/foobar/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', FooBarFetch.as_view(), name="foo_bar")
```

But I want to replace the `pk` in the url with something more descriptive like `foo_bar_id`.

Changing the `look_up_field` doesn't work as it still has to use the `pk` to perform the lookup.

Just kwrags key has to be changed in the url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I dug into the classes [`GenericAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) etc and found that it uses a field `lookup_url_kwarg` for this purpose.

By default, it is `None` and that makes the kwarg key to be `pk`
in the url.

We just need to override the field like :

`lookup_url_kwarg = 'foo_bar_id'`

Where `foo_bar_id` is the key used in url.